# How to reavaluate model in WEKA?

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I am trying to solve a numeric classification problem with numeric attributes in WEKA using linear regression and then I want to test my model on the existing dataset with ""re-evaluate model on current test dataset.

As a result of the evaluation I am getting the summary:

Correlation coefficient                  0.9924
Mean absolute error                      1.1017
Root mean squared error                  1.2445
Total Number of Instances               17

But I don't have results as it is shown here: http://weka.wikispaces.com/Making+predictions

How to bring WEKA to the result I need?

Thank you.

To answer my question - for trained and tested model, right click on the model and go to visualize classifier error. there use save option to save actual and predicted values.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using command line interface (CLI) or GUI.

If CLI, the command given in the above link works pretty fine

```
java weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -T unclassified.arff -l j48.model -p 0
```

So when you train the model you save it as *.model (j48.model) and later use it to evaluate on test data (unclassified.arff)

Comment: I am on GUI side. Thanks for your answer.